# Flutter: How to display data from 2 JSON based on the same value of Array

Tags: flutter

I have 2 JSON file:

json1: String people name ([API](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tft-test-48c87.appspot.com/o/name.json?alt=media&token=417cad4b-d492-4144-9bf4-5a25253e6994))

```
[
  {
    "name": "Oliver"
  },
  {
    "name": "George"
  },
  {
    "name": "Harry"
  }
]
```

json2: String outfit and an array of people who fit that outfit ([API](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tft-test-48c87.appspot.com/o/outfit.json?alt=media&token=b9185e07-4bbd-4057-abb6-4d7a7c9f99a3))

```
[
  {
    "outfit": "T-shirt",
    "fit": [
      "Oliver",
      "George"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outfit": "Hat",
    "fit": [
      "George",
      "Harry"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outfit": "Jacket",
    "fit": [
      "Harry"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want that when clicking on the name of the person => show outfits that fit them

*Ex. George fits a T-shirt and a hat*

[image]

So pls help me, this is the main file:

```
import 'package:ask/model/page1_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/model/page2_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/json2_service.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/json1_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  List<Json1> _json1 = [];
  List<Json2> _json2 = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Json1Services.getData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _json1 = data;
      });
    });
    Json2Services.getData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _json2 = data;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('List Name')),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _json1.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            Json1 json1 = _json1[index];
            return Column(children: [
              InkWell(
                  child: Text(json1.name),
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                                appBar: AppBar(title: Text('${json1.name} fits:')),
                                body: ShowWhatFit(json2: List<Json2>.from(_json2)..retainWhere((element) => element.fit[index] == json1.name)), // I think this line is not right
                              ))))
            ]);
          },
        ));
  }
}

class ShowWhatFit extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Json2> json2;
  ShowWhatFit({this.json2});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) Text(json2[i].outfit),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

..............................................................................

Comment: @EdwynZN's answer is worth a shot. Even if that doesn't work, I'll recommend you to use a HashMap to create a third json using json1 data as keys.

Comment: EdwynZN's answer worked perfectly for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hi @Kel, can you share your model and service file to me, I have the similar problem to show the data as in stackoverflow.com/questions/73732881/… but not yet resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Json2>.from(_json2)..retainWhere((element) => element.fit[index] == json1.name))
```

`retainWhere` will check every element and keep only those where the condition is true. the problem is `element.fit[index] == json1.name` just check the element at index `index` of the list `fit` and compares it with the name `json1.name`, doesn't really check if the name is in the list `fit`. Try:

```
List<Json2>.from(_json2)..retainWhere((element) => element.fit.contains(json1.name)))
```

That will iterate every elemnt in json2, then check if the list `fit` contains an equal object `json1.name` and returns true if there is one, otherwise false

Comment: It worked correctly, you helped me to learn something new. You are my hero xD

Comment: I would recommend checking best practices for NoSQL (Firebase) or SQL and how to implement relationship tables like this example https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data, it could help you later to improve further for maintenance

Comment: Got it, it looks very useful, I will try. Thanks :">

Comment: I have a [new post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251355/flutter-how-to-use-firebase-storage-to-get-new-data-if-json-file-in-firebase-st), Hope you can help me implement it :D

Comment: Hi @EdwynZN, can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732881/flutter-how-to-join-or-link-two-classes-in-a-json-file